# Send event to top level document from a frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frames

I'm working with legacy code and trying to add a jQuery onClick trigger to the **top level** parent document, but I can't seem to get it working. I'm honestly not sure how many frames deep this element will go.

This is a sub section of the web app from 1996-1999. Throughout the rest of the app clicking the button triggers a jquery-ui modal.

I have tried

```
<img id="help-button" 
     data-pagehash="Need This" 
     onclick="$('#help-button', parent.document).click()" 
     src="stuff" />
```

And

```
      onclick="window.parent.$('#help-button').trigger('click')"
```

But neither are working and neither are throwing errors. I'm not really sure what else to do. I really don't have much experience working with frames and since they are mostly antiquated, information on them is slim.

I also need to send the data attribute to the top level parent, if that makes a difference. I'm not sure if that is passed with the DOM object or not.

Comment: This sounds horrific...

Comment: First is it the same domain?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded in both documents or just the parent?

Comment: @epascarello jquery is loaded in the frame where this needs to be called and on the top level document. I know that each of these are set in stone, but what I don't know is if there are any other frames thrown between them somewhere in the app. If that makes sense... I know top level is `main.htx` and the page where the event is triggered is `toolbar.htx`, both of which have jquery.

Comment: @Zap7 If possible, can post `frame` `html` ? Can create jsfiddle ?

Comment: Try `window.parent` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_parent2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the same situation with a legacy app. `Window.top` will get you to the top level document if you are nested more than one deep, then you should be able to navigate down to the proper frame. To get your data attribute value use `onclick="window.top.frames[0].$("#help-button").trigger('click', [this])"` to pass the current button/image as an additional argument. Then you can grab the data from the top level binding like this:

```
$("#help-button").on("click", function(e, additionalArgs) {
   var data = 'some default value';
   if(additionalArgs) {
      data = $(additionalArgs).data('pagehash');
   }

   $("#dialog").text(data).dialog();
});
```

The additionalArgs value will be ignored for normal click events.